# Get quotes (active and inactive) for a customer

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, collection, sales-quote

The goal is to get all the **quotes for a given customer** (considering id, email, whatever).

But this quotes collection seems to work differently from those of customers and products.

### First attempt: getCollection

```
$quote_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
  //or //addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $customer->getEmail())
```

Gives a frustrating (even by filtering on created_at)

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted ...
```

To avoid messing around with server's memory, tried appending

```
  ->limit(10)
```

Which gives the error

```
Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection::limit()
```

Deserately, try to limit to only one result, using getFirstItem: **it works perfectly** and the code is now

```
$quote_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
  ->getFirstItem(); //->limit(10);
```

Too well in fact, since I do not want only one quote but all of them.

### Second attempt: getSelect

```
$quote_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
  ->getSelect()
  ->where('(customer_id='.$customer->getId().')');
Mage::log($quote_collection->__toString());
```

The sql is exatly what I want:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*
FROM `sales_flat_quote` AS `main_table`
WHERE ((customer_id=136))
```

Which gives 8 lines on the Magento [sample data](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ht_magento-ce-sample.data.html), for customer 136.

But I do not know a way to get the results from this query ([not even that](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-collection-functions/)), since

```
$quote_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
  ->getSelect()
  ->where('(customer_id='.$customer->getId().')')
  ->getItems();
```

Results in a error report telling:

```
Unrecognized method 'getItems()'
```

Any suggestion? TIA!

EDIT: Finally, the first part was nearlyy right, my memory issues were caused by some var_dump :)

The working code is

```
$quote_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());
foreach($quote_collection as $key => $quote)
{
  $quote_data=$quote->getData();
  Mage::log('quote '.$quote_data['entity_id'].')
  Mage::log('  created at '.$quote_data['created_at']);
  if($quote_data['is_active']) {
    Mage::log('  is active');
  }
  Mage::log('  $'.$quote_data['grand_total']);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $quote_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('subtotal')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 5);
    foreach ($quote_collection as $quote) {
        $data = $quote->getData();
        print_r($data);
    }
```

Or if you know which field you need, for example Subtotal:

```
$subtotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this foreach does not loop the collection. Here is the print_r of the $quote_collection for customer 136: http://pastebin.com/gG7myfrk

Comment: About your edit of 11h51 (GMT), got exactly what I am describing in "first attempt": PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 58285416 bytes)

Comment: Did you manage to check the size of sales_flat_quote table?  500Mb from sample data seems to be huge.

Comment: The table sales_flat_quote has 408 lines, total weighting 192,0 Kio ; I think this is a memory leak but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Many thanks, your first answer was good, my PHP skills were in cause. Now, hoping that table never go too big! :)